# Spring SpEL. How to set null as default value for field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to set variiable throw SpEL in spring boot application:

```
@Value("${data.jndi-name:#{null}}")
private String jndiDataSource;
```

`data.jndi-name` should comes from application-{profile}.properties. But field `jndiDataSource` always null even if `data.jndi-name` exists.

Code with `@Value("${data.jndi-name}")` work fine but `jndiDataSource` contains empty string.

My question is how to set null to variable if property does not exists using SpEL.

upd: values comes from profile specific property file

Comment: This actually works for me. Check if you are running under a certain spring profile?

Comment: This work well only when data comes from main application.properties. When data comes from profile profile specific property it's not work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Value("${data.jndi-name:@null}")
private String jndiDataSource;
```